# Вопрос по работе с json в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, dict

У меня есть json файл, в котором:

```
{
    "7283": {
        "name": "man",
        "money": 999288
        },
    "9937": {
        "name": "dog",
        "money": 28
        }
}
```

Как я могу обойти ключи 7283 и 9973, сразу получив `name` и `money`, для того чтобы сделать топ значений, который должен выглядеть так:

```
1. man: 999288
2. dog: 28
```

И возможно ли это?

Comment: что вы хотите получить на выходе - словарь, список словарей или просто вывести на печать?

Comment: Я хочу получить словарь, чтобы потом сортировать значения, и сделать из этого топ который нужно вывести на печать.

Comment: Приведите в вопросе пример словаря, который вы хотите получить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если просто вывести на печать

```
d = {
    "7283": {
        "name": "man",
        "money": 999288
        },
    "9937": {
        "name": "dog",
        "money": 28
        }
}
```

то так:

```
f = [(x['name'], x['money']) for x in d.values()]
for i, x in enumerate(f, 1):
    print(f'{i}. {x[0]}: {x[1]}')
```

выдаст:

```
1. man: 999288
2. dog: 28
```

Так, чтоб вывод был в порядке убывания по `money`:

```
for i, x in enumerate(sorted(f, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True), 1):
    print(f'{i}. {x[0]}: {x[1]}')
```